# Looking for a way to plot a pairwise scatterplot matrix where variables are in two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggally

Looking for a way to plot a pairwise scatterplot matrix where variables are in two groups, i.e. the plots need to be restricted to pairs between groups, excluding within-group pairs. For instance, the base `pairs()` produces this

```
    pairs(iris[1:4])
```

[image]

Whereas I am looking to, for example, correlate only sepal variables with petal variables, and am not interested in sepal (or petal) length-to-width correlations. So, instead of a 4x4 matrix, I'd need a 2x2 matrix.

The solution would look something like this

[image]

`pairs()` seems to support a formula argument, but `pairs(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=iris)` doesn't look right. It's in the right direction giving a 3x3 matrix, but for some reason the two sepal variables are grouped.

Preferably looking for a solution in `ggplot2` or `GGally::ggpairs()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vanilla ggplot approach with tidyr preprocessing.

First, we'll reshape the data such that the width and length variables have the same columns.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(iris, c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width), 
                          names_to = "petal_metric", values_to = "petal_value")
df <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width),
                          names_to = "sepal_metric", values_to = "sepal_value")
```

Next, we can simply facet on the petal/sepal metrics.

```r
p <- ggplot(df, aes(sepal_value, petal_value, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point()
  
p + facet_grid(petal_metric ~ sepal_metric)
```

[image]

We could decorate the plot a bit better to have the strips serve as axis titles.

```r
p + facet_grid(petal_metric ~ sepal_metric, switch = "both") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>